# error assigning values to a string literal array after definition

Tags: c++

when I try to intialize the string literal array at the point of the definition it works fine :

```
    char* arr[3] = { "ahmed"  , "saeed" , "ahmed" };
```

But when I try to assign these values to it after the point of definition it gives me an error starting from the second value :

```
char* arr[3] ; 

arr[3] = { "ahmed"  , "saeed" , "ahmed"};
```

what's the difference here and whats going on?

error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0146   too many initializer values structs_consts  

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2440   '=': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'char *' structs_consts
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is that one is initialisation, and the other is [attempted] assignment. Those are different constructs.

You cannot assign to an array. You just can't. Even if you could, you [probably] wouldn't be able to do it with initialisation syntax.

It's a rule from C. Why? No idea.

Once the array exists, you'll have to assign to its elements individually (be that directly, or via `std::copy`, or `memcpy` or some other such thing).

---

The specific compiler error is because you tried to do this using the expression `a[3]`, but that is not the name of the array. The name of the array is just `a`. `a[3]` is an element that does not exist.

The utterance of `a[3]` in the *declaration* means something different. Yes, it's confusing.

---

How about a nice game of `std::array<std::string_view, 3>`?